# How do I get "Hide/Show" and "add marker" functions to work together in Google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a page for my family tree website containing a google map with two additions (i) to add markers to show places linked to the family, and (ii) to "hide/show" Google's poi markers. 
By copying and pasting, I have managed to code an HTML page with one combined script which, when opened, only shows the "add marker" element. If I delete the "add marker" section of code I get the "Hide/Show" element only (as you would expect). Never both of them at the same time on the same map!
I strongly suspect that it has something to do with the fact I have duplicated the "function initMap" and "var map" commands, but if I delete one pair of these commands, I just get a blank page.
I have spent the last few days searching google maps API and the internet generally with no success, and it is driving me mad.
Can any of you good people out there share your knowledge and tell me where I am going wrong? As you may guess, this is my first venture into Javascript!!
THIS PROBLEM HAS NOW BEEN SOLVED AND THE WORKING CODE IS NOW SHOWN HERE:-

```
        <script>  
        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7, center: { lat: 52.85, lng: 1.16 },
        });

        var styleControl = document.getElementById('style-selector-control');            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(styleControl);

        document.getElementById('hide-poi').addEventListener('click', function () {
            map.setOptions({ styles: styles['hide'] });
        });
        document.getElementById('show-poi').addEventListener('click', function () {
            map.setOptions({ styles: styles['default'] });
        });

        var styles = {
        default: null,
        hide: [
          {
            featureType: 'poi',
            stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
          },

          {
            featureType: 'transit',
            elementType: 'labels.icon',
            stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
          }
        ]
      }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat:52.05,lng:1.16},
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
        });
        }

</script>
```

Comment: PatrickP - Thanks for the answer, your code works a treat, but I am afraid this was not what I am looking for . The Hide/Show element is wanted to switch off the google POI and transport markers so that there is less clutter on the map and my new family markers stand out. The viewer can show the Google markers again if they are interested in what is in the local area.  Whilst you were posting, I have also edited my question to show the whole HTML page as it currently stands. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add the marker(s) inside of the first `mapInit()`, get rid of the second:

```
function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: { lat: 53.82, lng: -4.74 },
            });

            var styleControl = document.getElementById('style-selector-control');
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(styleControl);

            document.getElementById('hide-poi').addEventListener('click', function () {
                map.setOptions({ styles: styles['hide'] });
            });
            document.getElementById('show-poi').addEventListener('click', function () {
                map.setOptions({ styles: styles['default'] });
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: 53.82, lng: -4.74 },
                map: map,
                title: 'Hello World!'
            });
        }
```

Comment: Patrick P- you are a star. Your code got the Hide/Show buttons and the marker on the map for the first time. Unfortunately the Hide/show buttons didn't work, but I added the var styles, deleted a stray "}" and the code works perfectly now. I have edited my post to show the full working code in case anyone else has the same problem. Thanks again.